# Error 403: Request had insufficient authentication scopes (reading from Google Sheets in iOS App)

Tags: swift, google-sheets-api

I am working on an app to interface and read from a google sheet.
I followed the quick-start guide in [this link](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/ios?ver=swift&hl=zh-cn).

I am making requests to the Google Sheets API using an Oauth 2.0 client ID, but it is giving me an error stating the request had insufficient scopes (Error 403), but I am unsure why since that is the scope that is stated in the Quick-start guide?  Not sure if the source of the error is in my setup in the Google Console or in my code below?  I set up an Oauth 2.0 Client ID within the Google Console and copied that into my app adding it to one of the URL types in Xcode. I am using the `kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsSpreadsheetsReadonly` scope.  Below is portion of my code performing the request in Swift.

```
private let service = GTLRSheetsService()
private let scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsSpreadsheets, kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsSpreadsheetsReadonly, kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsDrive]

service.authorizer = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser!.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()

let range = "Class!A2:H"

let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesGet
    .query(withSpreadsheetId: spreadSheetID, range: range)
service.executeQuery(query, delegate: self, didFinish: #selector(ImportStrengthPlansVC.displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:)))
```

Comment: Do you have previously stored credentials? Have you tried clearing it out and execute your code again?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 - what do you mean by clearing it out and executing the code again?

Comment: I am using Firebase authentication as well in this app, so I have an Oauth 2.0 client ID that I got from the GoogleService-info.plist file from the Firebase console, and I have an Oauth 2.0 client ID that I got from the GoogleService-info.plist file from the Google console to allow me to read from Google Sheets.  Would these client ID's be conflicting with one another?